# How to optimize data generation for numpy call

Tags: python, performance, numpy, functional-programming

I'd like to know how to make the following code shorter and/or more efficient.  Could I (or should I) get rid of the for loop by using a functional method, or is there method I should be using from numpy?

The code calculates the expected value of an array of of integers.

```
vals = np.arange(self.n+1)

# array of probability of each value in vals
parr = np.ones(len(vals))
for i in range(len(vals)):
    parr[i] *= self.prob(vals[i])

return np.dot(vals,parr)
```

As requested in comments, the implementation of the method prob():

```
def prob(self, x):

    """Computes probability of removing x items

    :param x: number of items to remove
    :returns: probability of removing x items
    """

    # p is the probability of removing an item
    # sl.choose computes n choose x
    return sl.choose(self.n, x) * (self.p**x) * \
           (1-self.p)**(self.n-x)
```

Comment: You should try Code Review

Comment: @PythonMaster Okay thank you!

Comment: What exactly is `prob()`?

Comment: @Divakar It calculates the probability of a given value.   It shouldn't be necessary to answer the question, but it is the probability mass function of a bernoulli random variable.

Comment: Could you share its implementation or import command if importing from some module?

Comment: What exactly is that code doing? You're basically setting each `parr[i]` to `prob(vals[i])`, right? Because you're always multiplying by 1 and `1 * vals[i]` is always equal to `vals[i]`. But then, why multiply at all?

Comment: @Divakar Sure thing -- edited.

Comment: @sepp2k I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but I initialize an array of ones so that I can multiply by the probability of each element in vals.  Once I have this I can compute the dot product of the two arrays, which is the expected value.  Its my understanding that the numpy functions are highly optimized and generally better than using lists and for loops so that is why I was doing it that way.

Comment: @Connor Let me ask this differently? If you replaced `*=` with `=`, the code would behave exactly the same way, right? Or am I missing anything? Then what's the point of multiplying, if it doesn't do anything? That's just confusing.

Comment: @sepp2k I see what you're saying.  You are correct; there is no point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop can be reduced to a list comprehension:

```
vals = np.arange(self.n+1)

# array of probability of each value in vals
parr = [self.prob(v) for v in vals]

return np.dot(vals, parr)
```

Comment: Nice!  Thank you.

Comment: list comprehension

Answer (score 3):

I think it will be most faster:

```
vals = np.arange(self.n+1)

# array of probability of each value in vals
parr = self.prob(vals)     

return np.dot(vals,parr)
```

and function:

```
def prob(list_of_x):

    """Computes probability of removing x items

    :param list_of_x: numbers of items to remove
    :returns: probability of removing x items
    """

    # p is the probability of removing an item
    # sl.choose computes n choose x
    return np.asarray([sl.choose(self.n, e) for e in list_of_x]) * (self.p ** list_of_x) * \
           (1-self.p)**(self.n - list_of_x)
```

Because numpy is faster:

```
import timeit

import numpy as np

list_a = [1, 2, 3] * 1000
list_b = [4, 5, 6] * 1000

np_list_a = np.asarray(list_a)
np_list_b = np.asarray(list_b)

print(timeit.timeit('[a * b for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b)]', 'from __main__ import list_a, list_b', number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit('np_list_a * np_list_b', 'from __main__ import np_list_a, np_list_b', number=1000))
```

Result:

```
0.19378583212707723
0.004333830584755033
```